# How to import mysql database through command line in advanced installer

Tags: mysql, advanced-installer

I try to use Advanced Installer 13.1 to make an installer for my C# project working with MySQL database.

I can connect MySQL database and also i can log in using Custom Actions tab in advanced installer  but i cannot continue to import my file(test.sql).

```
mysql> -h localhost -u root -p1234 dbtest < D:\test.sql
```

So i tried to run this on command prompt.It easily and successfully worked 
but cannot work in my advanced installer project.I don't know why.

Could you please to answer my question?

Here is a screen shot of my advanced installer project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue can be related to your [custom action's execution time](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/custom-actions.html) during the installation. If the custom action is immediate, "test.sql" file you added from the Files and Folders page in your Advanced Installer project is not yet physically present on the target machine.

To fix this you can try enabling the following options for the custom action:

Execution time: "When the system is being modified (deferred)"

Execution options: "Run under LocalSystem account with full privileges (no impresonation)"

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I can't.
Can I give me sample advanced installer project or link to accomplish importing external .sql file to Data folder which directory is declared by data_dir in .ini file using command line Launch file not using ODBC.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Comment: Thank you so much Naveed Ramzan. But this command line works in command prompt but cannot work in Advanced Installer.